# Cookie set with document.cookie not getting detected in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, browser, url-rewriting

Am setting one `Cookie`. Below is the code,

```
var myCookie="MyCookie";
document.cookie = myCookie+"="+escape("myValue")+ ";expires="+";path=/;";
```

This code is in my xhtml page. I could see this `Cookie` in Chrome and FF Browsers. But not in IE (IE7, 8, & 9)

Am basically trying to write a Rewrite rule in Apache web server using this `Cookie`. But, since this `Cookie` is not getting detected in IE, Rewrite is not happening. Whereas, its happening in Chrome and FF.

Below is the Rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Cookie}  MyCookie=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/web/portal/login
RewriteRule .* http://%{SERVER_NAME}/web/portal/home [R=302]
```

Why is `Cookie` set with `document.cookie` is not getting detected in IE?

Comment: I solved it by setting `Cookie` like below `document.cookie=myCookie+"="+1` . I dont know why it started working in IE when the `Cookie` was set like this. But, this was just a workaround and it still doesn't answer the question.